# Cannot import module in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, zoom-sdk

I tried to import zoom websdk module to next js but it failed because window object is not defined.

What i did is just trying to import websdk module but this error happened

[image]

I'm using nextjs v12 with create-next-app and my code is pretty simple.
here's on my `pages/index.js`

```
import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoomus/websdk';

const Page = () => {

    const handleClick = async () => {

    }

    return (
        <main>
            {/* get meeting number and role here (and password maybe) */}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Join meeting</button>
            {/* <div>{meetingUrl && <ZoomWindow url={meetingUrl} />}</div>  */}
        </main>
    )
}

export default Page
```

is the websdk package broken or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that NextJS runs both in the browser and on the server. During a server side render, `window` is not defined. You can use dynamic imports to only import some dependencies on the browser, where window will be defined.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Here is the example from `NextJS`

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

You can do essentially the same, but with your dependency.

Edit: I thought ZoomMtg was a component. The first example from the docs is closer to what you need for ZoomMtg.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
  const [zoomMtg, setZoomMtg] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
   ( async () => {
     if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
      const {ZoomMtg} = (await import('@zoomus/websdk'))
      setZoomMtg(ZoomMtg)
    }
    })()
  }, [])
```

Then just confirm `zoomMtg` the state variable is defined before rendering your component.
`{!!zoomMtg && <YourComponent />`

NOTE: If you have control over the `YourComponent` module, then a better alternative would be to move the import of `ZoomMtg` to this file and just import it normally. Then import `YourComponent` with the nextjs `dynamic` syntax.

Comment: how can i import { ZoomMtg } with that code?

Comment: Once I've had a chance to confirm the syntax I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @RobyCigar I updated the answer with a method that should do the trick for you... Is `ZoomWindow` your component or a built in zoom component? If it's yours then I wouldn't do it the way I suggest and I would just move the import of `ZoomMtg` into the component itself and use the dynamic import solution above on your component.  However, if you don't have control over `ZoomWindow` then my second solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue in nextjs after import module it will give
a error like this - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a  module. if you want to use module if it is not working in nextjs it is best solution and it is not a issue just configer setting if modules not working follow -

```
npm i next-compose-plugins 
npm i next-transpile-modules
```

##### next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
   "@project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter",
   "import another modules if not working..."
]);

module.exports = withPlugins([withTM], {
  pageExtensions: ["mdx", "md", "jsx", "js", "tsx", "ts", "cjs", "mjs"],
  distDir: "build",
  basePath: "",
  and config other... 
}
```

after this setting in next.config.js you can use module suppose make a new file demo.js in components and after this it will work.

##### demo.js

```
import Wallet from "@project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter";
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested this code, it works:

```
const Page = () => {

    const handleClick = async () => {
        alert("ok")
    }

    return (
        <main>
            {/* get meeting number and role here (and password maybe) */}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Join meeting</button>
            {/* <div>{meetingUrl && <ZoomWindow url={meetingUrl} />}</div>  */}
        </main>
    )
}

export default Page
```

Check your `@zoomus/websdk` lib, then

- `npm i` in your folder
- `re-run your project`

Comment: have u tried to import the module? with import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoomus/websdk';

Comment: checking now, it's problem with zoom lib

Comment: Just check the lib you are tried to use, clone it. https://github.com/AchrafAsh/next-zoom-starter

Comment: I already clone and run that repo in other day, but it still give me the same error :(